# Invertibility of the product of two elements in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,·)$ be a non-commutative ring. If $a\in R$ is invertible, and $x\in R$ is non-invertible, does that imply that $ax$ is non-invertible?

Comment: Invertible = Invertible from both sides?

Comment: Invertible from both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ax$ was invertible then lets call the inverse $y$. 
$$yax = axy =  e $$

Now lets multiply by $a^{-1}$
$$a^{-1}yax = xy =a^{-1}$$

Now multiply by $a$

$$xya = e$$

Therefore $x^{-1} = ya$

Comment: But x is non invertible so I suppose the answer is no since you've reached a contradiction.

Comment: @user528021 It's not a proof by contradiction, it's a proof of the contrapositive. If $ax$ is invertible, so is $x$. The contrapositive is "if $x$ isn't invertible, $ax$ isn't either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $b = (ax)^{-1}$, then $x^{-1} = b a$.